# Create a unique_ptr to an array with type double in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr

I am writing a constructor for a class containing the following:

```
// my_class.hpp
private:
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> my_list;
```

and I am facing some problems when trying to initialize **my_list**

```
my_class::my_class(const int new_size, const double new_values){
    // creating an array with new_values as initial value.
    auto size = static_cast<const size_t>(new_size);
    my_list = std::make_unique<double[]>(size);          // <-- Error
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        my_list[i] = new_values;
    }
}
```

**Error Message: "do not declare C-style arrays, use std::array<> instead [modernize-avoid-c-arrays,-warnings-as-errors]"**

I have tried the following:

```
    my_list = std::make_unique<std::array<double>>(size);    // <-- Error
    // Error Message: "too few template arguments for class template 'array' [clang-diagnostic-error]"
```

and

```
    my_list = std::make_unique<std::array<double,size>>(size);    // <-- Error
    // Error Message: "non-type template argument is not a constant expression [clang-diagnostic-error]"
```

How can I fix this problem and also is there any way to initialize such an array without looping through each element?

Comment: An std::array is a fixed size array. You probably want an std::vector. Read on both options and decide for yourself.

Comment: I've never really seen the use-case for `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` when we have `std::vector<T>`. If ownership semantics is wanted then `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>` is probably better (and a good use-case for pointers to containers, which is generally not common).

Comment: where you declare `magnitudes`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It can be useful when your legacy code hands you a pointer that you get to own and you want to avoid copying. I don't see a case for ever creating one "from scratch", though.

Comment: Your error is not coming from standard c++ and might be incorrect. It looks like it wants you to use only `vector`s in your code.

Comment: the code compiles fine. What you're looking at is not a compiler error. Maybe a warning. Maybe even just a note. But start using `std::vector<double>`

Answer (score 2):

> How can I fix this problem

Switch `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` to `std::vector<double>`.

> Is there any way to initialize such an array without looping through each element?

```
my_class::my_class(std::size_t new_size, double new_values) 
: my_list(new_size, new_values) 
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this problem.

1. keep your `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`, and you do not need to alter the rest of your code, but you need to replace these two lines

```
    auto size = static_cast<const size_t>(new_size);
    my_list = std::make_unique<double[]>(size);          // <-- Error
```

with this:

```
    my_list = std::make_unique<double[]>(new_size);  // allocates new_size of doubles
```

2. As Caleth pointed out, you can change the type of data member `my_list` from `std::unique_ptr<double[]>` to `std::vector<double>`, but then you need to change all the placed that access my_list.

> How can I fix this problem and also is there any way to initialize such an array without looping through each element?

If you keep my_list as unique_ptr, then you can use `std::fill_n(my_list.get(), new_size, new_values)` to initialize your array.

Comment: I am using solution 1 but I end up with a different error message "no matching function for call to make_unique"

Comment: Sorry, syntax error, it should be `std::make_unique<double[]>(new_size);`

Comment: solution 1 is not really required. What he's doing is redundant, but valid.